# Java FileInput/OutputStream and ByteBuffer

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, bytebuffer

How can I use ByteBuffer to write an integer 1432 into a file written by FileOutputStream. Since 1432 takes more than one byte, we cannot use write() method.
Furthermore, how can we get back the integer when we use FileInputStream read() method later?

I tried to use:

```
int i = 1432;
byte[] bytesi = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
fileOS.write(bytesi);
```

But when read the file:

```
int e = fileIS.read();
System.out.println(e);
int e1 = fileIS.read();
System.out.println(e1);
int e2 = fileIS.read();
System.out.println(e2);
int e3 = fileIS.read();
System.out.println(e3);
```

I get outputs like:

```
255
132
201
255
```

Comment: @jonasnas then how many bytes would be stored? If I use fileOS.write(i)

Comment: ok, got what you mean. you mean you can't use it directly

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using ByteBuffer to generate bytes from integer, you can use it for inverse convertion too

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
fis.read(bytes);
int x = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

XY problem. You don't need `ByteBuffer,` you need to write an int to a file in binary. `DataOutputStream` has all the methods you need, and it already works with `FileOutputStream.` Similarly `DataInputStream` already works with `FileInputStream.`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` into `DataInputStream / DataOutputStream` to have helper methods for various data types like `readInt / writeInt`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html

Example of usage: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/dataoutputstream_writeint.htm

Answer (score 0):

Same basic answer as above, using the ByteBuffer function but not messing around with your own byte[].

```
ByteBuffer bytesIn = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
fileIS.read(bytesIn.array());
int e = bytesIn.getInt();
```

You could/should do it this way for writing the bytes as well, e.g.

```
int i = 1432;
ByteBuffer bytesOut = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(test);
outFile.write(bytesOut.array());
```